# specify multiple generic implementations for parent class

Tags: c#, generics, architecture

I got a problem of specifying multiple possible classes implementation for my parent abstract class leveraging generic types. this so far works well:

```
public interface IMLModel<RQ, RS> where RQ: IMLModelRequest where RS: IMLModelResponse
{
    RS GetModel(RQ request);
}
public interface IMLModel_Class1<RQ, RS> : IMLModel<RQ, RS> where RQ: MLModelRequest1 where RS: MLModelResponse1
{
}
public interface IMLModel_Class2<RS> : IMLModel<MLModelRequest21, RS>, IMLModel<MLModelRequest22, RS>, IMLModel<MLModelRequest23, RS>
    where RS: MLModelResponse2
{
}

public abstract class AMLModel<RQ, RS> : IMLModel<RQ, RS> where RQ : IMLModelRequest where RS : IMLModelResponse
{
    abstract public RS GetModel(RQ request);
}
public class Class1<RQ, RS> : AMLModel<RQ, RS>, IMLModel_Class1<RQ, RS> where RQ : MLModelRequest1 where RS : MLModelResponse1
{
    public override RS GetModel(RQ Request) {
      //overrides the parent abstract method
      //return RS;
    }
}
```

the trick lies in implementing the *Class2* from *IMLModel_Class2*. i want to achieve to have specific implementations based on the input request param like this:

```
public RS GetModel(MLModelRequest21 request) // +override
{
    //implementation 1
}
public RS GetModel(MLModelRequest22 request) // +override
{
    //new implementation 2
}
public RS GetModel(MLModelRequest23 request) // +override
{
    //another implementation 3
}
```

but what I got is this not working code:

```
public class Class2<RQ, RS> : AMLModel<RQ, RS>, IMLModel_Class2<RS>
    where RS: MLModelResponse2
    where RQ: MLModelRequest21, MLModelRequest22, MLModelRequest23 // <--- cannot do that
{
    public override RS GetModel(RQ request) {
      //struggling here
    }
}
```

partially i was able to compile with:

```
public class Class2<RS> : AMLModel<MLModelRequest21, RS>,
        IMLModel_Class2<RS>
        where RS: MLModelResponse2
{
    override public RS GetModel(MLModelRequest21 request)
    {
      //overrides parent
    }
        public RS GetModel(MLModelRequest22 request)
    {
        //new implementation 2
    }
    public RS GetModel(MLModelRequest23 request)
    {
        //another implementation 3
    }
}
```

but that's not exactly what I am looking for, especially with having another more complicated implementations like Class4, Class5, etc coming. usually, I would just use Interfaces as input params instead of generics, but due to Dependency Injection of the target framework I must exactly define the input/output params (request types), thus I ended up with generics.

another view about this problem would be, **how to extend the parent class with multiple generics the same way it is possible with interfaces**? ie:
public interface IMLModel_Class2 : IMLModel,

```
public interface IMLModel_Class2<RS> : IMLModel<MLModelRequest21, RS>, IMLModel<MLModelRequest22, RS>, IMLModel<MLModelRequest23, RS>
where RS: MLModelResponse2
{
}
```

vs

```
public  class Class2<RS> : AMLModel<MLModelRequest21, RS>, AMLModel<MLModelRequest22, RS>, AMLModel<MLModelRequest23, RS> // <----- **cannot have multiple parent classes**
    where RS: MLModelResponse2
{
}
```

Comment: I can't work out why you want to inherit from multiple classes rather than implementing multiple interfaces. If you define Class2 such that it implements the same generic interface multiple times, but with a concrete class for each then you should get one GetModel() function per interface and function overloading should pick the correct version for you.

Comment: Couldn't `MLModelRequest21, MLModelRequest22 ,MLModelRequest21` implement another interface `IModelRequest` for instance?  Then the where clause would be  `where RQ: IModelRequest`

Comment: @SteveTodd the reason i mentioned in the text. because the target framework uses some sort of **dependency injection** and for mocking purposes it needs to have specific input and output values defined in the interface. it cannot just mock one universal method.

Comment: @FelixCastor they indeed do imeplement one parent ```IModelRequest```. but because the target framework and its Dependency injection mechanism it uses for mocking must have explicitly  defined parameters, i must them also explicitly define in the child interfaces

Comment: I have to say this looks like an absolute generics nightmare.

Comment: Rule of Thumb: If Generics are making your life complicated then you probably shouldn't be using them the way you are. Find another (better, cleaner) way.

Comment: @SteveTodd yes i wanted to have as less code duplicates as possible. i could easily swap back to the straightforward implementation where i would have to define the very parent interface method but with no body in each Class implementation, but thats another clear OOP abuse.

Comment: In this case the quest for "less code" is not making life easier to write or maintain it. Nor is creating empty classes. Define your interfaces, implement them and mock the implementations if you need to test them. Having multiple classes instead of Class2, each of which implements a specific IMLModel<RQ, RS> takes a little more typing but is much easier to handle.